# Flutter The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined in SweepGradient

Tags: flutter

in my project i want to use `SweepGradient` and when i try to use with this definition i get error:

```
Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const SweepGradient({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

my code implementations:

```
static final BoxDecoration _gradientBorderDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  // https://brandpalettes.com/instagram-color-codes/
  gradient: SweepGradient(
    colors: [
      Color(0xFF833AB4), // Purple
      Color(0xFFF77737), // Orange
      Color(0xFFE1306C), // Red-pink
      Color(0xFFC13584), // Red-purple
    ],
  ),
);
```

`SweepGradient` construct class:

```
const SweepGradient({
  this.center = Alignment.center,
  this.startAngle = 0.0,
  this.endAngle = math.pi * 2,
  required List<Color> colors,
  List<double>? stops,
  this.tileMode = TileMode.clamp,
  GradientTransform? transform,
}) : assert(center != null),
     assert(startAngle != null),
     assert(endAngle != null),
     assert(tileMode != null),
     super(colors: colors, stops: stops, transform: transform);
```

`flutter` version:

```
Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.153 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2e643651a9 (15 hours ago) • 2020-09-11 23:07:03 -0400
Engine • revision 16b900b63e
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-117.0.dev)
```

Comment: Did you use `@required` or `required` on `SweepGradient ` constructor?

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean?

Comment: Also, can you show pubspec.yaml file to see the libraries being used

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: @BilalAslam after flutte clean and invalidate cache/restart problem solved

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This happened to me as well after I upgraded to the latest stable flutter version 1.12. I fixed it doing following:

1. Type in terminal: flutter clean
2. Under File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart (click this option)

Afterwards everything worked like a charm again.

Comment: Thanks you, any idea why the error occurred in the first place?

Comment: yes. The problem is that the code checker within your android IDE sometimes doesn't get updated when you switch the channel. So you have to update your code checker via the terminal manually

Comment: Strangely this works for most of the bugs.

Comment: That's not really strange, the reason is that the cache sometimes does not get cleaned up correctly, so we have to do it manually

Answer (score 9):

Solution for VS Code:

1. run `flutter clean` from terminal.
2. close VS Code completely and run again.